RuntimeException on join across data sources on a string field
One table is in a CSV file, another in an SQLite database. After registering both schemas I perform a join operation:
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, name, age FROM `sqlite`.`user`) t1
JOIN (SELECT id, name FROM `csv`.`csv_user`) t2
ON t1.name = t2.name

This results in an error but on an integer type id it works.
My code:
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String sqliteUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:D:\\content\\user.sqlite";
    String driverClass ="org.sqlite.JDBC";
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Class.forName("org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver");
    String path = "D:\\git_workspace\\calcite\\src\\main\\resources\\csv_dir";
    CsvSchema csvSchema = new CsvSchema(new File(path), CsvTable.Flavor.SCANNABLE);
    try{
        Properties info = new Properties();
        info.setProperty("lex", "JAVA");
        info.setProperty("caseSensitive", "false");

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:calcite:", info);
        CalciteConnection calciteConnection = connection.unwrap(CalciteConnection.class);
        SchemaPlus rootSchema = calciteConnection.getRootSchema();
        DataSource sqliteDataSource = JdbcSchema.dataSource(sqliteUrl,driverClass,null,null);
        JdbcSchema jdbcSchema = JdbcSchema.create(rootSchema,"sqlite", sqliteDataSource,
                null,null);
        rootSchema.add("sqlite",jdbcSchema);
        rootSchema.add("csv", csvSchema);
        Statement stmt = calciteConnection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from (select id,name,age from `sqlite`.`user`)t1 join (select id,name from `csv`.`csv_user`)t2 on t1.name = t2.name");
//      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from (SELECT `name`, `id` FROM `A`.`user` )t1 left join (select `name` from csv.csv_user )t2 ON t1.name = t2.name ");
        CsvDefaultTest.printResultSet(rs);
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        LOGGER.error("error happens ", e);
    }
}

Exception trace stack:
18:20:26.555 [main] DEBUG o.apache.calcite.plan.RelOptPlanner [AbstractRelOptPlanner.java:367]- For final plan, using rel#75:BindableTableScan.BINDABLE.[](table=[csv, csv_user])
18:20:26.590 [main] ERROR c.e.calcite.CalciteCsvAndSqlite [CalciteCsvAndSqlite.java:54]- error happens
java.sql.SQLException: Error while executing SQL "select * from (select id,name,age from `sqlite`.`user`)t1 join (select id,name from `csv`.`csv_user`)t2 on t1.name = t2.name": While executing SQL [SELECT "id", "name", "age", CAST("name" AS VARCHAR CHARACTER SET "ISO-8859-1") AS "name0"
FROM USER] on JDBC sub-schema
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:56)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:41)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeInternal(AvaticaStatement.java:163)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeQuery(AvaticaStatement.java:227)
    at com.example.calcite.CalciteCsvAndSqlite.main(CalciteCsvAndSqlite.java:46)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: While executing SQL [SELECT "id", "name", "age", CAST("name" AS VARCHAR CHARACTER SET "ISO-8859-1") AS "name0"
FROM USER] on JDBC sub-schema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInstWithCause.ex(Resources.java:463)

How do I correctly do this? The join should be performed on a string field.
